# Simulating Esc key press and QML WebView

Tags: qt, webview, keypress, qml, simulate

I'd like to simulate the press of Esc key on the web view. But I can't find any way out. I thought about using QKeyEvent, and QApplication::postEvent, but I can't find any way to implement it

Thanks in advance

Marcin

Comment: This (https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-15496) has an implementation for Qt5 (if you are still interested).

Comment: If you promise to accept and upvote a working solution, I can try to work out one :)